# Google sheet script removes formulas when using a script to move data into another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created this google sheet to enter data for my work.

I have created the script below but the problem is when executed, it removes the formulas with the data in the cells.
I want to move the data from the "Load Sheet" spreadsheet to "Archives" without removing formulas in the cells in "Load Sheet" spreadsheet.

```
//Scripts for Day 1
// confirmation pop-up
function confirmMove1() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert("Are you sure you want to move day1 data to database?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    // Process the user's response.
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        moveData1();
    } else {}
}

// Copy data

function moveData1() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("load Sheet");
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A8:X12");
  var numRows = sourceRange.getNumRows();
  var numCol = sourceRange.getNumColumns();
  Logger.log(numRows);
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(sourceValues);
  
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archives")
  var range = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, numRows, numCol );
 range.setValues(sourceValues);
  
  
  sourceSheet.getRange("A8:X12").clearContent();
  
  Browser.msgBox("Data has been successfully moved");

}
```

Here is the link to the google sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172jL9R88t6oMGQLqwQ4Rqa_Zgj31cBuTRiu8b96VmBo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Then you probably don't want to do this `sourceSheet.getRange("A8:X12").clearContent();`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I want the numbers in those columns reset after it's moved to the other spreadsheet but the formulas should remain as they are.

Comment: Well then why does your current code have the clearContent?